# What Filesystem should be used for a 4TB drive for both Windows and OSX compatibility?

Tags: windows, macos, filesystems, external-hard-drive

Note: I am aware of similar questions. The one's I seen here are for Windows, OSX, and Linux (which I do not need). I also can use Mountain Lion, which the other questions did not mention.

I was going to use NTFS, but OSX Mountain Lion can only read that filesystem and not write to it for some reason. I want to use something native between OSX and Windows, as I don't want to risk losing the data over filesystem incompatibilities.

I have USB 3.0 and want something that will allow files greater than 4GB. I do not mind installing a small set of drivers on the Windows machine(s), but I would strongly prefer to leave the Mac machine untouched.

Thanks!

Comment: exFAT, a.k.a. FAT64 is probably the best you can use. You'll not lose any data, but you may have issues with metadata differences with the two systems.

Comment: Actually I don't think OS X can read exFat partitions.

Comment: @martineau: ExFAT support was added to OS X in version 10.6.5.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Oh, all I know is that it wasn't supported at some point, but since it is now, for anyone interested the exFAT driver for Windows can be downloaded from Microsoft [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955704).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use something native between OSX and Windows, as I don't
>   want to risk losing the data over filesystem incompatibilities.

Whatever you choose is going to require you formatting the current drive.

> have USB 3.0 and want something that will allow files greater than
>   4GB. I do not mind installing a small set of drivers on the Windows
>   machine(s), but I would strongly prefer to leave the Mac machine
>   untouched.

You should look at exFAT or simply choose a Linux file system ( i.e. ext4).  Windows should be able to read many of those, and OS X of course will also.  Any file system that these operating systems cannot read would require drivers for.

Comment: exFAT is probably a gopd choice. Windows can read ext4 drives using ext2fsd, but I'm having trouble getting my GPT-formatted 3TB external to mount. I would try various combinations of GPT/MBR formatting, one large and several smaller volumes, to see what works with both OSes. Also note that ext2fsd uses gigabytes of ram.